# MVC concept for web form using razor

Tags: .net, razor

I am fairly new to .NET and I am trying to get mt head wrapped around some simple form and validation syntax stuff.

I have a model ContactUs.cs which looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Presentation.Web.Models.FormModels
{
    public class ContactUs
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public String email { get; set; }
        public String comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my razor looks like this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
            <div class='form-group'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-3'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Your Name</label>
                        <input class='form-control' placeholder='your username' type='text'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-3'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Your Email</label>
                        <input class='form-control' placeholder='your password' type='text'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <label class='control-label'>Your Message</label>
                        <textarea class='form-control' name='' rows='4'></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
<input type="button" ID="sumbmit-contact-us" runat="server" name="Save" value="SUMBMIT"/>
```

I am struggling to figure out how to dynamically print the label and do validation check on submit. Also if I end up adding this into the HomeController.cs then How should the syntax look like?

Comment: @Dai-- I was actually following this post 
http://ryanbutler.org/ASPMVCForm

would you not recommend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML Helpers to render the inputs, labels and validation messages rather than raw markup. Also `runat="server"` is meaningless in ASP.NET MVC and Razor, as it's a WebForms ASPX feature.

You'll want this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.Name );
    @Html.TextBoxForFor( m => m.Name, new { placeholder="Your username" } );
</div>
```

and so on, for each input